# Problems install Ghost 0.5.0 - npm WARN unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ghost-blog

I get the follow error when trying to install Ghost on ubuntu,

Node version

```
node -v
v0.10.22
```

NPM version

```
npm -v
1.4.21
```

Install output

```
sudo npm install --production
npm WARN package.json express@4.8.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json moment@2.4.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json mysql@2.1.1 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/bookshelf requires semver@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/knex requires semver@'^2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.2.1
```

Recommendations appreciated!

Comment: You should NEVER use `sudo` to install any npm modules (even if they are global `-g`)

At this point I suppose your node installation is not correct since you are using `sudo`.

Which OS are you using? How did you install Node? Any chance you can upgrade it to latest version (0.10.30)?

Comment: I'm on `Ubuntu 13.10 x64`

Comment: Allright I upgraded node to v0.10.30, and even when i don't use `sudo` I get exactly the same warnings...

Comment: Also, the reason why I run `sudo npm` is because I get messages like this, for example when trying to upgrade `npm` itself: `npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/npm'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/npm' } Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.` UPDATE: I realize now my `usr/local` did not have proper permission, which I fixed with this tutorial, https://aralbalkan.com/scribbles/npm-install-g-please-try-running-this-command-again-as-root-administrator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done a download of the latest official release from here:
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/releases

Then I've run `npm install --production` and the only warning I get is this:
`npm WARN engine html-to-text@0.1.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.23"})`

Are you sure you've downloaded the latest release version and not the github repository instead or another version?

Try to install ghost from that link in a clean directory, without `sudo` and see if it's still giving you warning.

Answer (score -1):

sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable

//This will install the latest stable version or you can go to https://nodejs.org for the latest 'recommended for most users' version and use:

sudo n 4.6.0